# How can I enter values into a map with a struct as key?

Tags: c++, dictionary, struct, key, stdmap

I have a map with a `struct` as key, I have overloaded the `<` operator, but the map is storing each entry as separate keys even though they are same. The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

struct vertex 
{
    int color;
    vertex *pi;
    int index;

    bool operator<(const vertex & v ) const {
        return this->index < v.index;
    }
    bool operator==(const vertex & v) const {
        return this->index == v.index;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int x, y, num_edges;
    vector<vertex* > v;
    vertex *temp1, *temp2, *temp;
    map<vertex*, vector<vertex*> > m;
    map<vertex*, vector<vertex*> >::iterator it;

    cout << "\nEnter no. of edges: ";
    cin >> num_edges;

    for( int i = 0; i < num_edges; i++ )
    {
        cout << "\nEnter source: ";
        cin >> x;
        cout << "\nEnter dest: ";
        cin >> y;

        temp1 = new vertex;
        temp2 = new vertex;
        temp1->index = x;
        temp2->index = y;

        m[temp1].push_back(temp2);
        m[temp2].push_back(temp1);
    }
    
    temp1 = new vertex;
    temp2 = new vertex;

    cout << "\nPrinting map: " << endl;
    for( it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); it++ )
    {
        temp = (*it).first;

        cout << temp->index << "\t";

        v = (*it).second;
        for( int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ )
        {
            temp1 = v[i];
            cout << temp1->index << "\t";
        }
        cout << "\n";
        v.clear();
    }
    for( it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); it++ )
    {
        temp = (*it).first;
        v.push_back(temp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output that I am getting now is:

```
Enter no. of edges: 4

Enter source: 1

Enter dest: 3

Enter source: 4

Enter dest: 3

Enter source: 4

Enter dest: 2

Enter source: 2

Enter dest: 1

Printing map: 
1   3   
3   1   
4   3   
3   4   
4   2   
2   4   
2   1   
1   2
```

But it should be:

```
1 3 2  
2 4 1      
3 1 4  
4 3 2
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The std::map will compare the type you give it as key (`vertex*`), but you define the `<` operator on vertex.

You can use the struct themselves as keys, or -if you have to use pointers- you have to give the map a way to compare the pointers.

Now, `std::map` use the `std::less` as a comparison predicate, that is defined in therm of `<` (that's why using the struct themselves, you can achieve the result by overloading `<`).

You can either:

o) define yourself a predicate that compares vertex*: it can be

```
template <class T> //assume T is a pointer or pointer-like class
struct redirected_less : public std::binary_function <T,T,bool> 
{
    bool operator() (const T& x, const T& y) const {return *x < *y;}
};
```

and then define you map as

```
std::map<vertex*, vector<vertex*>,  redirected_less<vertex*> >
```

o) specialize the std::less for vertex* as

```
namespace std
{
     template <> 
     struct less<vertex*> : binary_function <vertex*,vertex*,bool> 
     {
         bool operator() (vertex* x, vertex* y) const {return *x < *y; }
     };
}
```

and declare your map as

```
std::map<vertex*, vector<vertex*> >
```

as usual.

I personally prefer the first (gives a more localized code, less "arcane" in future readings)

Comment: +1, even though I would provide two `redirected_less`, one taking `T` and implementing `operator()(T const &, T const&)` *without* dereferencing, and an specialization taking `T*` and implementing `operator()( T const*, T const* )` that dereferences, in the same way as `remove_const` or `remove_reference` metafunctions are defined --i.e. user code does not need to change if the `key` is changed from a value to a pointer type.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I got your point, but I was looking at a more uniform declaration 'std::map<vertex*, vector<vertex*>,  redirected_less<vertex*> >' respect to 'std::map<vertex*, vector<vertex*>,  redirected_less<vertex> >'

But it's much more a chicken and egg problem ... probably a higher  view on the context can turn more favor to one or the other ...

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia: Thanks a lot! Earlier i had replaced my pointers to struct with struct but with your way, i am now able to get my original code running! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use pointers as keys. If you have two structures, that are "the same" according to your rules, but they are allocated on the heap with `new`, then their pointers will never be the same.

Use the structures, not their pointers, as key.

Answer (score 1):

```
map<vertex*, vector<vertex*> > m;// its key type vertex*
```

m uses

```
bool operator < (vertex * const, vertex* const) ;
```

while ordering

So you need to overload

```
bool operator < (vertex * const, vertex* const);
```

we have a problem here. we can't overload on pointer. we could provide our own Compare function like this:

```
struct cmp{ 
      bool operator ()(vertex * const first, vertex* const second)
      { return first.index < second->index;} 
 };
cmp _cmp;
map<vertex*, vector<vertex*>, cmp> m(_cmp);
```

Comment: @fefe forget that. we could define an equivalent function or functor and pass it as map's template argument

Answer (score 0):

### C++11

[Emilio Garavaglia analyzed the problem with your code and how to fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8293145/2675154) very well. However, if you can use [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) features, then you can modernize your solution a bit. For example, you can use a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) instead of defining `operator<` for your struct, and pass it to the map's constructor. This approach is useful if you can't modify the struct that you want to store in your map or if you want to provide different comparison functions for different maps. [Range-based `for` loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) save you from having to deal with iterators and the placeholder [`auto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) saves you from having to specify lengthy container element types. I'd also like to mention that you don't need to specify `operator==` for your map to work.

#### Solution with `vertex` as key

For the sake of clarity I replaced the user input with hard-coded values:

```
struct vertex {
    int color;
    vertex *pi;
    int index;
};

int main() {
    auto comp = [](const vertex& v1, const vertex& v2) { return v1.index < v2.index; };
    std::map<vertex, std::vector<vertex>, decltype(comp)> m(comp);

    // Replace user input.
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> edges = { {1, 3}, {4, 3}, {4, 2}, {2, 1} };

    // Fill the map.
    for(auto const &e : edges) {
        vertex temp1;
        vertex temp2;
        temp1.index = e.first;
        temp2.index = e.second;
        m[temp1].push_back(temp2);
        m[temp2].push_back(temp1);
    }

    // Print the map.
    std::cout << "Printing map:" << std::endl;
    for (auto const &kv : m) {
        std::cout << kv.first.index << " =>";
        for (auto const &v : kv.second)
            std::cout << " " << v.index;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Printing map:
> 1 => 3 2
> 2 => 4 1
> 3 => 1 4
> 4 => 3 2

**Note:** If you can use [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17), then you can further shorten the code for printing the map by using [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding), as shown [here on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b6cf0aa91be513f).

#### Solution with `vertex*` as key

Basically, you have to replace all occurrences of `vertex` in the above code with `vertex*`. In addition, you have to ensure that the lambda expression does not compare the given pointers, but the content of the structs to which the pointers refer:

```
auto comp = [](const vertex* pv1, const vertex* pv2) { return pv1->index < pv2->index; };
std::map<vertex*, std::vector<vertex*>, decltype(comp)> m(comp);
```

You also have to make sure that you delete all dynamically allocated vertices at the end. For example, you can empty your map properly in the following way:

```
for (auto const &kv : m)
    for (auto const pv : kv.second)
        delete pv;
m.clear();
```

[Code on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/94300f11d0dc0ad6)

**Note:** In order to ease memory management, you should prefer to store [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) in the map, such as [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).